# I am creating an API in PHP and using curl opertaion, i am receiving and able to send data by using my curl but after some time i get this error "

Tags: php, curl

I send data many times by using same curl function. So my API works fine for some minutes ( approx 30 minutes), but after some time its start to show this error but I have tried this solution

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

but still getting an error.

Please help me.

Comment: error is  string 'Error in cURL request: SSL connection timeout'

Comment: You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)